# SuiteCRM increase autocomplete time in EditView

Tags: autocomplete, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm looking at a request from our customer to either lengthen the autofill or just remove it all together when adding an organisation in EditView.

e.g: https://demo.suiteondemand.com/index.php?module=Opportunities&action=EditView&return_module=Opportunities&return_action=DetailView
If you start typing into "Account Name" box 'A' it'll show all the Organisations starting with **A** but also it'll autofill the first result into the input box.

Is there a way to stop that autofill of the input box from happening or delay it?

Thanks

Edit: changed title to SuiteCRM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/Application_Framework/Quicksearch/

I used the Metadata example, and it worked.

[Edit]
To expand on the answer. If you want to remove autofill from any of the boxes you need to add the 'sqsNoAutofill' to achieve this you can do the following:

In a modules editviewdefs.php (e.g. modules/**(*module*)**/metadata/editviewdefs.php) locate the name of the input you wish to change e.g:

```
array (
        'name' => 'assigned_user_name',
        'label' => 'LBL_ASSIGNED_TO',
      ),
```

then add the following:

```
array (
        'name' => 'assigned_user_name',
        'label' => 'LBL_ASSIGNED_TO',
        'displayParams' => array (
            'class' => 'sqsEnabled sqsNoAutofill'
         )
      ),
```

This will stop an input box with a quicksearch drop down from autofilling.

You can also make the change to the SugarField for Parent
include/SugarFields/Fields/Parent/EditView.tpl (line 51):

```
<input type="text" .... class="sqsEnabled sqsNoAutofill" .....>
```

I hope that helps someone else.